# Maximize the plot in network visualization

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am making a large network visualization with 748 vertices and 2228 edges.

It looks similar to the plot produced in this:

```
library(networkDynamic) 
library(network) 
library(sna) 
library(intergraph) 
library(igraph)

# Set up data set.seed(123) 
g <- barabasi.game(750)

# Plot data 
  plot.igraph(g,
     margin = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
     rescale = TRUE,
     edge.arrow.size= .2,
     vertex.size = 4,
     vertex.label=NA)
```

[image]

Is there any way to avoid vertices from clustering together?

I tried to set the margin so that the plotting region can be maximized, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you loading all those packages? Your code only needs `igraph` I suppose. You might want to look [here](http://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_.html).

Comment: that's write, I copy that from the codes I am working on and forgot to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

I think best to use `qgraph` to obtain a Fruchterman-Reingold layout. Before `igraph` too could do it, but in the recent version the algorithm has been rewritten and it lost this feature. It was not my idea to use `qgraph` I have seen somewhere but don't remember where, sorry for missing credits.

```
library(igraph)
library(qgraph)

make_fr_layout <- function(g){
    # layout with qgraph
    # g is an igraph object
    el <- get.edgelist(g, names = FALSE)
    lo <- qgraph.layout.fruchtermanreingold(el, vcount = vcount(g),
                                            area = vcount(g)^2.3,
                                            repulse.rad = vcount(g)^2.1,
                                            niter = 3000)
    lo
}

set.seed(123)
g  <- barabasi.game(750)
lo <- make_fr_layout(g)

cairo_pdf(filename = 'nice-layout.pdf')

    plot.igraph(g,
        layout = lo,
        margin = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
        rescale = TRUE,
        edge.arrow.size = .2,
        vertex.size = 4,
        vertex.label = NA)

dev.off()
```